# Android list item expansion to fullScreen View animation

Tags: android-studio, android-animation, material-design, android-transitions

I trying to achieve behavior which is shown in [Material Design Specs](https://material.io/design/components/lists.html#behavior).

Considerations section of  Visual continuity on Pre Lollipop devices.

So basically i need to create some kind of View transition to other View animation. Is there is any particular library that can do that? Or i should write my own?

In my case there is no shared Views, just this one animation.  Actually also animation to back to list.